# 401 Unauthorized on authenticationManager.authenticate() (Spring Security)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

**401 Unauthorized** produced when trying to login while registration works perfectly fine.

During debug i've spotted that response is given on the line where method  `authenticationManager.authenticate()` at `UserController` is called. Another thing i noticed is that for some reason i haven't had this issue while working with **JPA** Repositories rather than **DAO**.
I'm using PostgreSQL

[image]

Here is code for corresponding method if `UserController`:

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/auth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public AuthResponse authenticate(@RequestBody AuthRequest req){
        authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(req.getUsername(), req.getPassword()));
        String token = jwtService.generateToken(req.getUsername());
        return new AuthResponse(token);
    }
```

**JwtFilter.doFilterInternal():**

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authorizationHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        String jwtToken = null;
        String username = null;
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            jwtToken = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwtToken);
        }
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtService.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails.getUsername())) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
```

**SecurityConfig.configure():**

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().httpBasic();
    }
```

**UserService.loadUserByUsername():**

```
@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService, UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User userByName = userDao.getUserByUsername(s);
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userByName.getUsername(), userByName.getPassword(), userByName.getAuthorities());
    }
}
```

**DAO query:**

```
@Override
public User getUserByUsername(String username) {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE username = ?", new Object[]{username}, User.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that query did not return excpected value. I changed:

```
 @Override
public User getUserByUsername(String username) {
    List<User> userList = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE username = ?", new Object[]{username}, (resultSet,i) -> {
        System.out.println(1);
        return new User(resultSet.getInt("id"),
                resultSet.getString("username"),
                resultSet.getString("password"),
                resultSet.getString("role"));
    });
    return userList.get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a JWT issue.
In the row: `.and().addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)`
Use the Debug to see,  what do you have in there as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.19.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html#authenticate-org.springframework.security.core.Authentication-) :

```
An AuthenticationManager must honour the following contract concerning exceptions:

A DisabledException must be thrown if an account is disabled and the AuthenticationManager can test for this state.
A LockedException must be thrown if an account is locked and the AuthenticationManager can test for account locking.
A BadCredentialsException must be thrown if incorrect credentials are presented. Whilst the above exceptions are optional, an AuthenticationManager must always test credentials.
Exceptions should be tested for and if applicable thrown in the order expressed above (i.e. if an account is disabled or locked, the authentication request is immediately rejected and the credentials testing process is not performed). This prevents credentials being tested against disabled or locked accounts.
```

I'm guessing your authenticate is throwing one of these three exceptions (or possibly some other exception). You need to look at your logs to determine which one, or catch the exception and debug it.